# В чем разница между == и equals в Java?

Tags: java, equals

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в коде ниже `==` и `equals` дают одинаковый результат?

```
import static java.lang.System.*; 
public class A { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        B b1 = new B("one","two"); 
        B b2 = new B("one", "two"); 
        B b3 = b1; 
        // ==
        out.println(b1 == b2);      // false
        out.println(b1 == b3);      // true
        out.println(b2 == b3);      // false
        // equals
        out.println(b1.equals(b2)); // false
        out.println(b1.equals(b3)); // true
        out.println(b3.equals(b2)); // false
   } 
} 

class B { 
    public B(String prop1, String prop2){ 
        this.prop1 = prop1; 
        this.prop2 = prop2; 
    } 
    private String prop1 = null; 
    private String prop2 = null; 
}
```

Comment: Если Вы решили свой вопрос, пожалуйста, выберите какой либо ответ как решение (галочка слева от ответа). [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

Т.к метод `equals()` не переопределен, то данный метод сравнивает ссылки, так же как и оператор `==`. Это можно увидеть, если взглянуть исходный код метода `equals` класса `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    return (this == obj); 
}
```

А если `equals()` переопределен, возьмем, например, класс `Integer`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    if (obj instanceof Integer) { 
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue(); 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

то:

```
Integer a = new Integer(6); 
Integer b = new Integer(6); 
System.out.println(a == b);  
// false т.к. это разные объекты с разными ссылками 
System.out.println(a.equals(b));  
// true, т.к equals() переопределен и сравниваются уже не ссылки
```

Чтобы сравнивать классы, нужно переопределить метод `equals()` (а тогда следует переопределить и `hashCode()`).

Answer (score 1):

### [Метод `equals()` в сравнении с операцией `==`](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/)

---

> Метод `equals` сравнивает символы из объекта типа `String`, а операция
>   `==` - две ссылки на объекты, определяя ссылаются ли они на один и тот
>   же экземпляр.

В примере отображено два разных объекта типа `String`, которые могут содержать одинаковые символы, но ссылки на эти объекты при сравнении *не будут равнозначны*:

```
// метод equals() в сравнении с операцией ==
public class EqualsNotEqualTo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Сравнение";
        String s2 = new String(s1);

        System.out.println(s1 + " равно " + s2 + " -> " + s1.equals(s2));
        System.out.println(s1 + " == " + s2 + " -> " + (s1 == s2));
    }
}
```

Переменная `s1` ссылается на экземпляр класса `String`, созданный присваиванием ей строкового литерала `"Сравнение"`. А объект, на который ссылается переменная `s2`, создается с использованием переменной `s1` в качестве инициализатора.

Таким образом, содержимое обоих объектов типа `String` одинаково, но это *разные объекты*. Следовательно, переменные `s1` и `s2` ссылаются *не* на один и тот же объект, поэтому они не равны, в сравнении операции `==`.

### Результат:

```
Сравнение равно Сравнение -> true
Сравнение == Сравнение -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод equals() обозначает отношение эквивалентности объектов. Эквивалентным называется отношение, которое является симметричным, транзитивным и рефлексивным. Но мы можем переопределять метод equals, задавая логику сравнения двух объектов. Отличия equals() от операции == в классе Object нет. Eсли объект ни на что не ссылается(null), то вызов метода equals этого объекта приведет к NullPointerException. У String equals перегружен. Оператор == (в случае с примитивными типами данных) сравнивает значения переменных и возвращает результат, НО в случае со ссылочными типами данных (объекты, массивы и т.д.) сравнивает ссылки на объекты в памяти компьютера, и на основании равенства или неравенства ссылок возвращает результат (true или false).

Comment: Перегрузка процедур и функций на уровне общей идеи, как правило, не представляет сложности ни в реализации, ни в понимании. Однако даже в ней имеются некоторые «подводные камни», которые необходимо учитывать. Разрешение перегрузки операций создаёт гораздо больше проблем как для реализатора языка, так и для работающего на этом языке программиста.