# В чем разница между "==" и методом .equals java

Tags: java

В java две переменные можно сравнивать с помощью ==, например

```
 String s1 = "Mystr";
 String s2 = "Mystr";
 if (s1==s2){
 System.out.println "string 1 equals to string 2"
 }
```

Но также сравнение можно провести с помощью метода equals, например

```
if (s1.equals(s2)){
    System.out.println "string 1 equals to string 2"
}
```

Операция "==" и метод equals чем-то отличаются (кроме того, что equals метод, а == — операция)? Или они действуют совершенно одинаково? Если есть отличия, то какие? Каким способом сравнения лучше пользоваться и в каких случаях? Буду благодарен за подробный ответ.

Comment: Оператор `==` используется для сравнения ссылок, метод `equals` обычно сравнивает значения. При этом Java не поддерживает пользовательскую перегрузку операторов, а метод `equals` можно переопределить.

Comment: Даже лучше вот этот: [В чем разница между == и equals в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/849411/186999)

Comment: `"str" == new String("str") ` - это будет `false`, а это: `"str".equals(new String("str"))` - отработает как `true`